# PhantomJS has crashed in CentOS for Arm

Tags: javascript, centos, arm, phantomjs, echarts

My server os is centos 7.9 for arm.
I build phantomjs bin by myself, and when i inject js like below

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("about:blank", function(status) {
  page.injectJs('jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
  page.injectJs('echarts.min.js');
}
```

I get below error message

```
1   0x17e5360 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x17e5360]
2   0x1819254 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1819254]
3   0x16a6d84 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x16a6d84]
4   0x16a7bfc /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x16a7bfc]
5   0x16b821c /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x16b821c]
6   0x16a46a4 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x16a46a4]
7   0x1745d20 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1745d20]
8   0x795064 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x795064]
9   0x7952ac /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x7952ac]
10  0x7900d0 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x7900d0]
11  0x776c90 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x776c90]
12  0x48843c /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x48843c]
13  0x44b44c /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x44b44c]
14  0x44b6f0 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x44b6f0]
15  0x480064 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x480064]
16  0x481be0 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x481be0]
17  0x1d14bd0 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1d14bd0]
18  0x7ac524 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x7ac524]
19  0x1625edc /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1625edc]
20  0x16b1b20 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x16b1b20]
21  0x16b5828 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x16b5828]
22  0x169eea8 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x169eea8]
23  0x1740c84 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1740c84]
24  0x163abfc /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x163abfc]
25  0x7a86bc /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x7a86bc]
26  0x7a879c /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x7a879c]
27  0x1d14bd0 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1d14bd0]
28  0x1d2b2b4 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x1d2b2b4]
29  0x47f548 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs(_ZN7WebPage12loadFinishedERK7QString+0x24) [0x47f548]
30  0x438058 /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x438058]
31  0x48013c /root/report/service/phantomjs-prebuilt_linux/bin/phantomjs() [0x48013c]
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
```

i try inject jquery only, all will ok, but inject echrats(only or with jquery) get this error

so what this error message means? or where can i get phantom's logs?
and how to resolve this error?

Comment: You have a stack trace; did you try running a debugger against it? You said you built it yourself, so you might want to rebuilt with debug symbols (`-g` for gcc/clang) to get better stack traces.

Comment: @omajid how can i build with debug symbols? i use `python build.py` before

Comment: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs seems to have a `configure` script and `CMakeLists.txt`. Are you building it some other way? Or, perhaps, I misinterpreted what you wrote and you aren't building phantomjs itself?

Comment: I follow https://phantomjs.org/build.html this page way to build